# passing a function as parameter to a remote server via ssh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I am wondering if its possible to pass a whole function as parameter to a remote server to do a long list of action on remote server and return the control flow back to the local server.

In shell/bash script.

for example:

something like below:

```
test_abc() {  
    # this function perform a long list of commands to be performed on remote server  
    command 1;   
    command 2;  
    .  
    ..  
    command N;  

    few echo commands;    
}  

ssh user@remote_server test_abc;
```

I am not sure even this is possible in shell scripting. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, a remote system will have no way of understanding anything in from your local environment.  "test_abc" would have to be a command known on "remote_server".

```
ssh user@remote_server "$(cat <<- _EOF_
((command-list))
_EOF_
)"
```

That, or quote the body of "test_abc", but it may require fiddling to get quoting correct.

Comment: got error ,Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: ssh user@server "$( cat <<'EOT'
echo "These commands will be run on: $( uname -a )"
EOT
)"